# UIWebView is crashing at the end of loading a page that contains embedded YouTube clips in iOS 4.0x

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, ios4, youtube

When I load a page that contains embedded YouTube clips in a UIWebView managed by a modal UIViewController then I crash out with this stack trace:

```
OS Version:      iPhone OS 4.0.2 (8A400)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   YouTube                         0x00002bac -[NSData(YTBase64) webSafeBase64Data] + 76
1   YouTube                         0x000026aa -[YTDeviceAuthenticator _authenticate2] + 662
2   YouTube                         0x00002a54 -[YTDeviceAuthenticator connectionDidFinishLoading:] + 504
3   Foundation                      0x0003d422 -[NSURLConnection(NSURLConnectionReallyInternal) sendDidFinishLoading] + 62
4   Foundation                      0x0003d3a4 _NSURLConnectionDidFinishLoading + 72
5   CFNetwork                       0x00010e74 URLConnectionClient::_clientDidFinishLoading(URLConnectionClient::ClientConnectionEventQueue*) + 160
6   CFNetwork                       0x00004b70 URLConnectionClient::ClientConnectionEventQueue::processAllEventsAndConsumePayload(XConnectionEventInfo*, long) + 96
7   CFNetwork                       0x00004e62 URLConnectionClient::ClientConnectionEventQueue::processAllEventsAndConsumePayload(XConnectionEventInfo*, long) + 850
8   CFNetwork                       0x00004a60 URLConnectionClient::processEvents() + 64
9   CFNetwork                       0x00004a12 URLConnection::multiplexerClientPerform(RunLoopMultiplexer*) + 30
10  CFNetwork                       0x00004990 MultiplexerSource::perform() + 120
11  CFNetwork                       0x0000490e MultiplexerSource::_perform(void*) + 2
12  CoreFoundation                  0x00071a86 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 6
13  CoreFoundation                  0x00073768 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 376
14  CoreFoundation                  0x00074504 __CFRunLoopRun + 224
15  CoreFoundation                  0x0001d8e4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
16  CoreFoundation                  0x0001d7ec CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
17  GraphicsServices                0x000036e8 GSEventRunModal + 108
18  GraphicsServices                0x00003794 GSEventRun + 56
19  UIKit                           0x000062a0 -[UIApplication _run] + 396
20  UIKit                           0x00004e10 UIApplicationMain + 664
21  MyApp                           0x00002e94 main (main.m:13)
22  MyApp                           0x00002e30 start + 44
```

This is not limited to one specific URL; it seems to happen whenever the page contains embedded YouTube clips, eg [this one](http://techcrunch.com/2010/08/28/square-the-perfect-solution-for-tricky-drug-and-prostitution-transactions).

Other web pages load fine without a crash.

The crash happens before I can even get to clicking on the actual YouTube clip; it happens as the page containing the embedded clip finishes loading, before the `webViewDidFinishLoad:` delegate method is called (if I set a delegate).

I stripped out all my extra code, including removing all `UIWebViewDelegate` references and it still crashes in the same way when running as part of my app.

Strangely, when I extract the code into a new app, the new app works fine.

I also only see this on an iPhone 3GS running iOS 4.02 and an iPod Touch running iOS 4.0.

I do **not** see this crash on an iOS 3.1.3 original iPhone, nor do I see a crash on the emulator.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I solved this myself.

I had a category of `NSData` in my code that defined the method:

```
- (NSString*)base64Encoding
```

Unfortunately, the YouTube plugin in iOS 4 appears to use a hidden method (of a category?) of `NSData`:

```
- (NSData*)base64Encoding
```

Needless to say, my category was overriding this method, causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is your view controller (or another class) a `UIWebViewDelegate` for your `UIWebView`? If so, can you show the code for the delegate methods you implemented?

Comment: I removed all the UIWebViewDelegate code, and it still crashed; I'll edit my post to make that clear

Comment: BTW your answer should really be a comment

Comment: @David Jacobson I was trying to start a dialogue to help you solve your problem. Would you like me to delete my answer?

Comment: Sorry if I came across as a bit testy; I do appreciate you trying to help, and your comment did inspired me to tighten up my question ... but it's not an answer, and (in my humble opinion) shouldn't use the answer mechanism :-)